# pytest only runs first test in file

Tags: python, pytest

I'm working on the Code-dojo Tennis Kata and I'm stuck with the silliest problem. My pytest stops after running the first test in the file. My test file looks like this:

```
from tennis import game
import re

def test_game_start(capsys):
    MaxVsMimi = game()
    MaxVsMimi.result()
    out, err = capsys.readouterr()
    assert bool(re.search(r'Love : Love', out))
    
def p1_scores_once(capsys):
    MaxVsMimi = game()
    MaxVsMimi.score("p1")
    MaxVsMimi.result()
    out, err = capsys.readouterr()
    assert bool(re.match(r'^abc', out))
```

This is the code:

```
class game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.scorep1 = "Love"
        self.scorep2 = "Love"
        
    def result(self):
        print(self.scorep1, ":", self.scorep2)
```

and the output:

```
:stdout:
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.6, pytest-6.0.2, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /usr/local/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /sandbox
collecting ... collected 1 item

test_tennis.py::test_game_start PASSED                                   [100%]

============================== 1 passed in 0.01s ===============================
```

Why does it not run the second "p1_scores_once" test?

Thanks!

Comment: The test functions in pytest must be named with the `test_` prefix or  a "_test" suffix, otherwise pytest ignores them.

Comment: I knew it would be something simple! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pytest, like many testing libraries including `unittest` require all test functions to have the word `test` in the start of the name. You can fix your code simply by changing the name of `p1_scores_once`:

```
def test_p1_scores_once(capsys):
    ...
```

Now the automatic test-finding system will treat the function like a test case.

Comment: That's it. Had to be something simple. Thanks!